# How to keep the value of a field entered via a drop-down list after submit

Tags: select, default

I have a form where people can enter informations to search on a database. The input is in the form :

logical-operator       criteria (text to search)

there are six lines like that. The first one cannot contain the logical operator which is "and" or "or".
I try to use a drop-down list for the operator. It works but... after the submit button is pressed, the results are displayed under the list of criterias, the criterias are displayed but I don't find how the logical operator could be preset to the valus entered before the submit.
It would be useful for those who want to modify their search and submit again.

The form is :

```
  <body>
     <h1 style="text-align: center;color: #004c99;">Actes notariés transcrits</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            <br />
            <h2 align="center">Recherche de termes dans un acte</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form name="add_name" id="add_name" method="post">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="critere" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="head">
                                        <th>Op&eacute;rateur</th>
                                        <th>Crit&egrave;re</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr>
                            <td>    <input type = "text" size="5" maxlength="5" list="operateurs" name="operateur[]" style="height:30px; width:40px" value="---" readonly />
                        
                            <td><input type="text" name="composant[]" placeholder="Critère de recherche" style="height:30px" value="<?php echo $Composant[0]; ?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <select id="operateurs-1" name="operateur[]" value="<?php echo $OP[1]; ?>">
                                <option value="ET">ET</option>
                                <option value="OU">OU</option>
                            </select></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="composant[]" placeholder="Critère de recherche" style="height:30px" value="<?php echo $Composant[1]; ?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <select id="operateurs-2" name="operateur[]">
                                <option value="ET" selected>ET</option>
                                <option value="OU">OU</option>
                            </select></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="composant[]" placeholder="Critère de recherche" style="height:30px" value="<?php echo $Composant[2]; ?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                            </tr>
```

and so on for the next lines.
I am new to PHP programming...

Any idea to keep the values previously entered?

Comment: OK, forget that request, I modified the design so that I don't need it anymore !